# Javascript table group products

Tags: javascript, html

I have table with products:

```html
<table border="0" color="black" id="table_serv" style="font-size:10px;" width="100%">   <thead>    <tr>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9; width:5%"></th>     <th style="text-align: left;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:45%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Description</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Selling Price</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Quantity</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Total</strong></span></span></th>    </tr>   </thead>   <tbody>                <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">8</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Declaration 020/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">0,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>0,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">6</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Declaration 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">20,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>20,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">3</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">10,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>10,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>                <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">6</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Declaration 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">20,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>20,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">3</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">10,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>10,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>                <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">3</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">45,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>45,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">2</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 004/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">5,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>5,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td colspan="5" style="background:white"></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Sub Total</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">110,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Discount</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">0,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Total</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">110,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:2px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Tax 27,00%</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;;border-bottom:2px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">29,70 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Grand Total</strong></td>     <td style="background:white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>139,70 €</strong></span></span></td>    </tr>   </tbody>  </table>
```

I need group products, where name and selling price is same. And I need sum quantity and total column of existing products. I have javascript:

```
const tbl = document.getElementById("table_serv");
const existProducts = {};
[].forEach.call(tbl.querySelectorAll("tr td:first-child"), function(el) {
    if (existProducts[el.textContent]) {
        existProducts[el.textContent].count = existProducts[el.textContent].count + parseFloat(el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent);

        existProducts[el.textContent].el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent  = parseInt(existProducts[el.textContent].el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent) + 1;
        existProducts[el.textContent].el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML  = '<span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>' + existProducts[el.textContent].count + ' €</strong></span>';
        el.parentNode.remove();
    } else {

        existProducts[el.textContent] = {

            count: (existProducts[el.textContent] || 0) + parseFloat(el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent),
            el:el
        }
    }
});
```

But my code is not working correctly. I need check and product name if same, and selling_price if same and then group products. If selling_price is different and product name is same, then I don't neeed group products. How I can do this? I need this table on result:

```html
<table border="0" color="black" id="table_serv" style="font-size:10px;" width="100%">   <thead>    <tr>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9; width:5%"></th>     <th style="text-align: left;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:45%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Description</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Selling Price</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Quantity</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Total</strong></span></span></th>    </tr>   </thead>   <tbody>                <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">8</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Declaration 020/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">0,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>0,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">6</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Declaration 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">20,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white">2</td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>40 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        
<tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">3</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">10,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white">2</td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>20 €</strong></span></td>    </tr><tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">3</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">45,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white">1</td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>45,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>                                                <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">2</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 004/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">5,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>5,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td colspan="5" style="background:white"></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Sub Total</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">110,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Discount</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">0,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Total</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">110,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:2px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Tax 27,00%</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;;border-bottom:2px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">29,70 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Grand Total</strong></td>     <td style="background:white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>139,70 €</strong></span></span></td>    </tr>   </tbody>  </table>
```

Now my code working like this:

```js
const tbl = document.getElementById("table_serv");
const existProducts = {};
[].forEach.call(tbl.querySelectorAll("tr td:first-child"), function(el) {
    if (existProducts[el.textContent]) {
        existProducts[el.textContent].count = existProducts[el.textContent].count + parseFloat(el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent);

        existProducts[el.textContent].el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent  = parseInt(existProducts[el.textContent].el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent) + 1;
        existProducts[el.textContent].el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.innerHTML  = '<span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>' + existProducts[el.textContent].count + ' €</strong></span>';
        el.parentNode.remove();
    } else {

        existProducts[el.textContent] = {

            count: (existProducts[el.textContent] || 0) + parseFloat(el.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.textContent),
            el:el
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<table border="0" color="black" id="table_serv" style="font-size:10px;" width="100%">   <thead>    <tr>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9; width:5%"></th>     <th style="text-align: left;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:45%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Description</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Selling Price</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Quantity</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Total</strong></span></span></th>    </tr>   </thead>   <tbody>                <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">8</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Declaration 020/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">0,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>0,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">6</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Declaration 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">20,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>20,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">3</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">10,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>10,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>                <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">6</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Declaration 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">20,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>20,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">3</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">10,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>10,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>                <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">3</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">45,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>45,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">2</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 004/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">5,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>5,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td colspan="5" style="background:white"></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Sub Total</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">110,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Discount</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">0,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Total</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">110,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:2px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Tax 27,00%</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;;border-bottom:2px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">29,70 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Grand Total</strong></td>     <td style="background:white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>139,70 €</strong></span></span></td>    </tr>   </tbody>  </table>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could include a working example of your code in the question. (Instead of pasting your code in 3 seperate blocks)

Comment: @DeanMeehan it's done. Check please.

Comment: If you run the Code Snippit there is an error.

Comment: @DeanMeehan check please output of table.

Comment: This data come from a server? Isn't it rendered from an object that contain all the info, so you don't have to iterate through DOM elements?

Comment: @Adrian Pop Yea from a server, and I need process data with javascript.. I can't edit output from server side..

Comment: I'm not saying to edit the data INSIDE the server, but once you get the result from there, you should be able to play with the object however you want. This won't affect the data in the server in any way. You should be able to play with the response from the sever before calling the function that renders the actual table. Why can't you do that? Are there any restrictions?

Comment: @AdrianPop I can't. I need change table on javascript side.

Comment: And did I say something different? Once you got your response from the server, you are on the `javascript side` or client side. I'm guessing that after you get the response, you call a function do generate your table. I don't understand why you can't just squash your data with another function in between and call the drawing function afterwards.

Comment: @AdrianPop I need change my current code js and group correctly products.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Object#values, Array#reduce, String#replace, Map, Array#forEach, Number#toFixed, and more.

This problem is very complex and is completely dependant on your HTML structure. This means that once you've changed your structure you'll need to modify the code below.

It would be **much better** to generate your HTML from an array of object data.

```js
const data = document.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

function stringToNumber(str){
 return Number(str.replace("€", "").trim().replace(",", "."));
}

function numberToPrice(num){
  return num.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",")
}

const res = Object
.values(data)
.reduce((a,tr)=>{
  const [name, price, quantityStr] = Object.values(tr.querySelectorAll('td'))
  .splice(1,3)
  .map(ele=>ele.textContent.replace(/(\n|\ |\t)*/g, ""));
  
  if(!name || !price || !quantityStr) return a;
  
  const quantity = stringToNumber(quantityStr);
  
  const key = `${name}|${price}`;
  //console.log(key);
  if(a.has(key)){
    const exists = a.get(key);
    exists.quantity += quantity;
    a.set(key, exists);
    tr.remove();
  } else {
    a.set(key, {tr, name, price, quantity})
  }
  return a;  
}, new Map());

[...res.values()]
.forEach(({tr, quantity, price})=>{
   const [quantityEle, totalEle] = Object.values(tr.querySelectorAll("td"))
   .splice(3,2);
   quantityEle.textContent = numberToPrice(quantity);
   totalEle.textContent = numberToPrice(quantity*stringToNumber(price)) + " €";
})
```

```html
<table border="0" color="black" id="table_serv" style="font-size:10px;" width="100%">   <thead>    <tr>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9; width:5%"></th>     <th style="text-align: left;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:45%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Description</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Selling Price</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%;border-right:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Quantity</strong></span></span></th>     <th style="text-align: center;color: white;font-weight: 600;background:#BDB9B9;width:15%"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="color:#000000;"><strong>Total</strong></span></span></th>    </tr>   </thead>   <tbody>                <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">8</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Declaration 020/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">0,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>0,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">6</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Declaration 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">20,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>20,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">3</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">10,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>10,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>                <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">6</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Declaration 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">20,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>20,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">3</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">10,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>10,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>                <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">3</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 010/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">45,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>45,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">2</span><br>     &nbsp;</td>     <td style="text-align:left; border-bottom:2px solid white;border-right:2px solid white;">     <h3 style="color: rgb(27, 155, 184); font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal; margin: 0px 0px 0.2em;">Certificate 004/2011&#8203;</h3>     </td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">5,00 €</span></td>     <td style="border-right:2px solid white;border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">1,00</span></td>     <td style="border-bottom:2px solid white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><strong>5,00 €</strong></span></td>    </tr>        <tr>     <td colspan="5" style="background:white"></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Sub Total</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">110,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Discount</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">0,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:1px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Total</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">110,00 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white; border-bottom:2px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">Tax 27,00%</span></td>     <td style="background:#BDB9B9;;border-bottom:2px solid #BDB9B9"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;">29,70 €</span></td>    </tr>    <tr>     <td colspan="4" style="background:white;"><strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Grand Total</strong></td>     <td style="background:white"><span style="font-family:verdana,geneva,sans-serif;"><span style="font-size:12px;"><strong>139,70 €</strong></span></span></td>    </tr>   </tbody>  </table>
```

Comment: But why total sum does not stack?

Comment: @BlogSER because I haven't updated the total. Check now.